# Jupyter notebook installing pip packages into wrong conda environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pip, conda

Thanks for any help / info on this:

I have several conda environments, each with ipykernel installed and visibly available as kernel choices in jupyter notebook.

The notebook I ran runs fine, pip packages get installed and it completes with no errors.

The problem is that I'm trying to avoid intermingling packages from one notebook to others, so I have multiple conda environments and multiple kernels related to those environments.

structure:

- I am starting the jupyter notebook server from within the activated BASE conda environment.
- I am selecting "dev" as my python kernel
- I have a "dev" conda environment that has ipykernel installed

Problem:

- ran the notebook, using the selected "dev" kernel
- the pip packages got installed into "BASE" conda environment and not "DEV"...

So I've officially mangled my setup..  exactly what I was trying to avoid...

Expected behavior:

- pip packages should be installed into the conda environment that is attached to the kernel that is selected in jupyter notebook (right??)
- the pip packages should be installed into "DEV" conda environment since this is the kernel I have selected...

Am I missing something?  Do the packages only get installed into the conda environment where I start the jupyter server?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't give us a lot of information to tell what you are specifically doing. As just one example, you don't say how you install, you just write, 'the pip packages got installed into "BASE" conda environment and not "DEV".' Did you use the magic install command inside your notebook running with the DEV kernel, such as `%pip install rich` run in a new cell? I do know though to best avoid intermingling you have to use `conda` to do installs and not `pip`. Anaconda/conda is your primary package manager, as you choose that. With `pip` not involved, your environments will be robust & portable.

Comment: Did you check `%pip -h` or `!which pip` to verify that `%pip` and `!pip` correspond to the environment you wanted? Otherwise, one can always guarantee correction environment context with `conda run`. E.g., `!conda run -n dev pip install foo`.

Comment: The other issues would be 1) using `--user` flag, which effectively install to all of user space whenever a common Python version is used; 2) not actually having `python` installed yet in the environment; 3) one has mucked around with `PATH` incorrectly and put the **base** environment at higher priority.